# Transfer byte stream to HDFS using JAVA

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Is it possible to upload a file using some web-service directly to HDFS space. I tried to write file in to local system and moved it to HDFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WebHDFS** provides REST APIs to support all the filesystem operations.

Direct uploading is not possible though.

It has to follow 2 steps

1. Create File in the hdfs location `http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=CREATE`
2. Write to that file - by specifying your `local file path` tat u want to upload     in the Header `http://<DATANODE>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=CREATE`

Refer APIs here [WebHDFS apis](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html)